# Autocomplete - callback on selected option

Tags: ng-zorro-antd

Is it possible to fire callback after option selection?
What I want is fire a callback when user selects option either with click or enter

Answer (score 4):

Use [this undocumented output](https://github.com/NG-ZORRO/ng-zorro-antd/blob/master/components/auto-complete/nz-autocomplete.component.ts#L123) like `<nz-autocomplete #auto (selectionChange)="onSelect($event)">`.

Answer (score 4):

To fire a callback after option selection, invoke selectionChange on nz-auto-option, 
which would pass the event, and the option selected

```
 <nz-autocomplete #auto  [nzBackfill]="true" >
   <nz-auto-option *ngFor="let option of pastSearchOptions" (selectionChange)="fieldSelected($event, option)" [nzValue]="option">{{ option }}</nz-auto-option>
 </nz-autocomplete>
```

on making a selection by click or enter, event would be true and for navigation it would be false

```
  fieldSelected(event: any, name: any) {
    if (event.isUserInput) {
      //do something
      console.log("Option got selected "+ name);
    }
  }
```